# Insert space into string

Tags: php

Could anyone tell me how to insert a space in between characters in a string using PHP, depending on the length for a UK post code?

e.g. if the string is 5 charterers, insert a space after the second character? If it is 6 characters insert after the third etc?

Comment: So, you always want the space to come after the second character, when counting backward from the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use regex:
`$formatted = preg_replace('/([a-Z0-9]{3})$/', ' \1', $postalCode);`
Note that this only works on alphanumeric characters, but I'm assuming that's what the scope of the input should be.